# Setting Up Log4J in IntelliJ IDEA 13

Tags: java, log4j

I'm building a simple app in IntelliJ IDEA 13 and can't seem to figure out how to get log4j working. My app is a simple demo that I made to make sure I could build something functional, all it does is multiply two random numbers and uses apache tomcat to put it on a localhost that I can access via my browser.

Here is the class code:

```
package Sample;

log4j-api-2.0.jar;
log4j-core-2.0.jar;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;


public class HelloWorld {

    public static double getMessage() {
        return Math.random()* Math.random();

     }

    private static Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    log.debug("Debugging Message");
    log.info("Informational message");
    log.warn("Warning Message");
    System.in.read();

}
```

I'm getting the error "class or interface expected" at the import lines and jar file lines so I don't think I've placed the corresponding files in the right directory. That's also causing the rest of the logging lines (from private static Logger... on) to generate errors.

Comment: You should remove the two lines with the filenames on them, they are unnecessary and likely causing the syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

**1.** The following isn't valid Java:

```
log4j-api-2.0.jar;
log4j-core-2.0.jar;
```

You *only* need the `import` lines, e.g.,

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;
```

**2.** The `.jar` files must be associated with your project.

You can:

- Right-click the "External Libraries" section and add them that way, or...
- Use Maven and add them as project dependencies, or...
- Use some other dependency management and/or build tool, e.g., Ant + Ivy, Gradle, etc.

**3.** You need to move the logging statements into a place where code is valid, like in a method:

```
package sample;

import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.LogManager;

public class HelloWorld {
    private static final Logger log = LogManager.getRootLogger();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        log.debug("Debugging Message");
        log.info("Informational message");
        log.warn("Warning Message");
    }    
}
```

Comment: I had the files in the web/web-inf/lib directory which was suggested in a tutorial I looked up for setting up log4j but now I've removed the two lines and am still getting errors on the import statements 'unused import' and 'cannot resolve symbol apache'. Does this mean that it's not finding the jar files where I put them? IntelliJ won't let me move the .jar files into the external directory, only the web-inf file

Comment: @user3748486 They need to deployed as well, unless your container also uses Log4J. Putting them in your project's `WEB-INF/lib` is okay for now, but you still need to add those jars to your module's dependencies. Note that you can locate them anywhere you want by moving them from the command line or your OS's file browser etc.

Comment: Once I've added the jar files as dependencies should the rest work, i.e. are the log.debug... and the next 3 lines proper commands?

Comment: @user3748486 Not really, since they live outside of any method or static block. Please consider a quick Java tutorial before going too much further, then check out the Log4J docs. If you put them in, say, a `public void static main(String[] args) { ... }` method and run that logging will work however you've configured it to.

Comment: @DaveNewton How I can place log4j2 properties file in IntelliJ IDEA? I am facing this error, `ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found.`

Comment: @DaveNewton, how could I find where the `.jar` is?  For existing project in which the statement including `log` works. However, for newly created project, I do not know where to import the `.jar` of log4j.  I am using IDEA Gradle.